# Fail2ban regex misses log entries

Tags: regex, fail2ban

I've been working with F2B regexes long time. Yet new kind of probing against my VPS drives me crazy since F2B regex doesn't catch those log entries.

**Log entries** (which are missed):

```
|  Oct 25 09:58:34 localhost sshd[17381]: Disconnecting invalid user admin 185.246.128.25 port 22937: Change of username or service not allowed: (admin,ssh-connection) -> (root,ssh-connection) [preauth]
|  Oct 25 09:59:02 localhost sshd[17385]: Disconnecting authenticating user root 185.246.128.25 port 33103: Change of username or service not allowed: (root,ssh-connection) -> (,ssh-connection) [preauth]
```

**F2B regex** (in sshd.conf):

```
^Disconnecting (?:authenticating|invalid) user .+ <HOST>%(__on_port_opt)s: .*%(__suff)s$
```

This regex works perfectly in every online regex tool (regex101, debuggex, etc), but when I test it against my log with:

```
fail2ban-regex /var/log/auth.log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/sshd.conf --print-all-missed > missed.txt
```

it misses all those lines.

I have tried multiple options and variations and yet unable to find working solution to this. Please, help to find working solution unless it's some kind of bug. Thanks.

**Update 1**: Here is for instance simplest form which also doesn't work: https://regex101.com/r/evQkT1/1

**Update 2**: It's totally strange and begins to look like a bug to explore, but I have replaced standard tag `<HOST>` with `\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+` and filter started to work...

Comment: In your example one "invalid" line is missed because the user doesn't have a name. Change `user .*` to `user .*?` and all lines are picked up. (see https://regex101.com/r/evQkT1/2 ) Also, the snippet you posted above starts with `^` which usually matches the beginning of the line, so it makes sense that none of your lines is in your result list.

Comment: @MichaelA.Schaffrath, thanks for comment. I would survive one missing line ;) Thanks though for the idea, I'll change to `.*?`. Regarding `^` symbol - that's how Fail2Ban works. I need to start custom regex with this symbol since everything before that is caught automatically.

Comment: If you want to know how this was fixed - I have just edited `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and changed `PermitRootLogin` to `no` and also added list of allowed users. These log entries disappeared. So read more articles on hardening your ssh.